# Is App.TaskVisible property applicable to Standard EXE?

Tags: syntax, vb6

Well, my question is not "how to hide" my application form Task Manager Applications tab, but only if I can do that using *App.TaskVisible* property and in Standard EXE?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc353bw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The property is commonly used to prevent a user from closing an
>   application that was designed to run as a background task. In most
>   cases, the TaskVisible property is used with applications that do not
>   display user interfaces.

That exactly pass to my case, but for my regret this property do nothing for me. 
Maybe it applicable to ActiveX EXE only? Or I miss something?

[EDIT]
Ok, I have the feeling that this property is dead, as I cannot bring it to life ever in simple project that contain only standard bas module with Sub Main. Also the last (most fresh) comments online about this property are about 10 years old.

Shortly, to isolate that issue...

1. Create new Standard EXE project;
2. Add Standard Module (.bas);
3. Remove the Form1;
4. Add the code below to your Module1;
5. Compile and run your Project1.exe from it location;

```
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

    Private Sub Main()
        App.TaskVisible = False
        Sleep 4500
    End Sub
```

Tested on Win8, Win7 and WinXP x64 SP2 and the process is task visible in all of them.

[**EDIT**] I reask about this in a bit different form and I've got answer, so here is the [answer of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299826/1856504).

Answer (score 0):

This might help answer your question (i.e. you should go to the source, i.e. the VB6 docs, not some .Net view of reality):

[TaskVisible Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445725%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

> The TaskVisible property can only be set to False in applications that do not display an interface, such as ActiveX components that do not contain or display Form objects. While the application displays an interface, the TaskVisible property is automatically set to True.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the VB6 docs! I'm afraid that the info there is ambiguous. My application as well _"not display an interface"_ nor yet _"contain or display Form objects"_, and should I translate _"such as ActiveX components"_ to _"ONLY ActiveX components"_?

Comment: No, it does not apply only to ActiveX components.  I think you need to start another question that asks more directly about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only set it in design time, and not while it's running.

Try setting it in design time.

Comment: Interesting... I with to try but my project contain only standard bas modules. Where I can do this at design time?

Comment: Create a blank form.  Make it your startup item.  Then set it, then just call your mod.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but still the same result. I'll edit my question to post what I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have used App.TaskVisible=False very successfully in a standard VB6 EXE - I set it in the start-up module (Sub Main), after I've done some preliminary checks. The EXE - which, incidentally, does indeed have a user interface/main form - does not display in the applications column in Task Manager but is still listed under processes. This is fine, as I just want to make it that bit more difficult for users to terminate the application. There's nothing sinister in this requirement, it is simply a messaging application - if it's stopped, the messages stop.